# Arduino IDE and esp8266 arduino-crypto library

Tags: c++, encryption, arduino, aes

I am using [arduino-crypto](https://github.com/intrbiz/arduino-crypto) for my ESP8266. I'm not running into any errors but I do have an issue that I hope you can solve for me.

This code:

```
#define BLOCK_SIZE 16

uint8_t key[BLOCK_SIZE] = { 0x1C,0x3E,0x4B,0xAF,0x13,0x4A,0x89,0xC3,0xF3,0x87,0x4F,0xBC,0xD7,0xF3, 0x31, 0x31 };
uint8_t iv[BLOCK_SIZE] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

char plain_text[] = "1234567890ABCDEF1234567890ABCDEF";

  // encrypt
  int length = 0;
  bufferSize(plain_text, length);
  char encrypted[length];
  encrypt(plain_text, encrypted, length);

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Encrypted: ");
  Serial.println(encrypted);

  Serial.println(length);
  Serial.println(strlen(encrypted));
```

Works just fine and gives me an encryption value of:

> Encrypted: y3QzsGi6cYiy3GGs31jXvTY8VI2OrlxsohOasiw4pgP+54gWXtUZPrjuRvOfyRTz

Now if i do both encrypt and decrypt then it decodes it just fine.

However, when i just run the decryption and copy the encrypted value and then run this:

```
// decrypt
  char* encrypted = "y3QzsGi6cYiy3GGs31jXvTY8VI2OrlxsohOasiw4pgP+54gWXtUZPrjuRvOfyRTz";
  int length = strlen(encrypted);
  char decrypted[length];
  decrypt(encrypted, decrypted, length);
  Serial.print("Decrypted: ");
  Serial.println(decrypted);
```

It outputs this in the console:

> Decrypted: ⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮j⸮Ҏ⸮R|;⸮⸮1234567890ABCDEF

It has a few original message letters/numbers in there but not sure why its not decrpting it like it does when you run both back-to-back.

What can be done in order to fix this?